# how to retrieve all records from one table in join with current month records

Tags: android, sql, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I have 2 tables in my Sqlite database one is USER and other is PAYMENTS

USERS:

```
ID  Name
"1" "shan"  
"2" "Abc"   
"3" "Def"   
"4" "Whi"
```

PAYMENTS:

```
ID  UserID  PayDate         Amount 
"1" "1" "2013-10-27"    "700"
"2" "1" "2013-11-12"    "700"
"3" "2" "2013-09-12"    "800"
```

How to retrieve all users and those user who paid the amount of the current month. i also want all users who didn't paid yet.

Comment: i m trying in sqlite and i have tried this
Select Users.Name,Users.HouseNo,strftime('%Y-%m-%d', Payments.PayDate) as Date from Users
Left join Payments
on 
Users.ID=Payments.UserID 
where
strftime('%m', Payments.PayDate) < strftime('%m', '10')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try somthing like this:

```
SELECT Users.Name 
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Payments
  ON Users.ID = Payments.UserID
WHERE Payments.PayDate = <date you are looking for>
```

You can also use WHERE PayDate BETWEEN 'date1' and 'date2'
This should return all users and payment will be NULL if there is no payment record.

Comment: all users are coming only untill i haven't use where clause. But after writing my where clause it showed only users that paid the amount

Comment: Thanks @Kairan i did it i did a little change with your query
like this in where clause
WHERE Payments.PayDate between '2013-10-1' AND '2013-10-31'  OR Payments.PayDate IS null